# How do i use #include with exporting modules?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

```
module;
#include <iostream>
export module modultest;
export class Test{
    public:
    Test(){}
    void print(){
        
    }
};
```

I want to create a `print` function using `cout`, which I need `<iostream>` for, but if I include `iostream` I get multiple errors, for example:

```
error: redefinition of 'void operator delete(void*, void*)'
  180 | inline void operator delete  (void*, void*) _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT { }
```

I'm using g++ compiler in VSCode.

Comment: Does the order of `#include` vs. `module` matter here?

Comment: module-declaration is only permitted as first declaration so switching #include with module doesn't work.

Comment: This is a compiler bug. GCC don't really support modules yet. Try with clang or MSVC

Comment: First: If you just want to play around, I suggest downloading the (free) Community Edition of Visual Studio. Microsoft seems to be way ahead with its implementation of modules compared to gcc. Second: I tried to run your code in Visual Studio. Your module compiled perfectly, but I got a weird compiler error in module main, where I had put function `main`, and also imported module `modultest`.  The program would not run, until I had put `#include <compare>` in the _global module fragment_ of module main! When I did, everything ran fine.

Comment: Although it is still deemed to be "experimental," and is not yet recommended for production code, Microsoft implemented `import std` a few months back. _It is sweet!_ Using `import std`, the only Standard Library headers you need to include in the _global module fragment_ are headers such as `<assert.h>`, which depend on macros. Those should be included in their C form. You will get errors if you include headers like `<cassert>`, which wrap the C functions with `namespace std`.

Comment: `import std` is now part of the C++ Standard. It was [added in C++23](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/standard_library#Importing_modules). _No more wasted time checking which name goes with with which header!_ Microsoft claims faster compile times with `import std` than you get when individual Standard Library modules are imported separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per cppreference.com:

[Importing modules and header units](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules#Importing_modules_and_headers)

> ...
>
> **[`#include`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include) should not be used in a module unit** (outside the *global module fragment*), because all included declarations and definitions would be considered part of the module. Instead, headers can also be imported as *header units* with an *import declaration*:
>
> > **export**(optional) **import** *header-name* *attr*(optional)**;**
>
> A header unit is a separate translation unit synthesized from a header. Importing a header unit will make accessible all its definitions and declarations. Preprocessor macros are also accessible (because import declarations are recognized by the preprocessor).
>
> ...

So, try replacing `#include <iostream>` with `import <iostream>;` instead.

Comment: Weirdly, OP's code was correct since the include was in the global module fragment. I highly suspect a GCC bug since GCC don't have a good module support

Answer (score 3):

Actually, your code is correct. Includes need to be put in the global module fragment:

```
module; // global module fragment
#include <iostream> // correct, inside the global module fragment

export module modultest; // named module declaration

// module purview, owned by module modultest
export class Test {
    public:
    Test(){}
    void print(){
        
    }
};
```

This code is correct since everything after `module;` lives in the global module fragment, which is okay to include anything there. You then declare the named module, and anything else after that is part of the module itself.

The error you encounter is a compiler bug. This is because GCC has very poor support for module at the moment. Expect your code to work with other compiler or future version of GCC.